# Reference to Source Projects in a Multiroot Workspace context

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, bazel

I have an issue and spent days of googling without finding my answer.
I have the following tree on my disk :

I have a workspace folder on my disk and several java projects inside.
I have a .code-workspace file to load all of them inside VS Code.

I build every project using Bazel. It gives me as output a "bazel-bin" folder inside each java project directory which contains both jars for sources and classes.

In VS Code, i set up my Workspace so as to have all projects loaded and configured as follow :

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": {
  "include": [
    "<absolute_path_to>/bazel-bin/*.jar",
    "<absolute_path_to>/bazel-bin/*.jar",
    "<absolute_path_to>/bazel-bin/*.jar",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "bazel-out",
    "bazel-testlogs"
  ],
  "sources": {
    "<absolute_path_to_>.jar":"<absolute_path_to>-src.jar",
    "<absolute_path_to_>.jar":"<absolute_path_to>-src.jar",
    "<absolute_path_to_>.jar":"<absolute_path_to>-src.jar",          
  }, 
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
    "src",
    "src/main/java",
    "java",
    "java/api",
    "java/impl",
 ],
```

The compilation runs well, BUT, whenever I try to navigate (e.g. using go to definition), I end up within the Jar, (that is the result of one of the Java project being compiled) which is well mapped with sources, instead of navigating to the sources in the project directly (which is present in the Workspace and shows up well in the explorer).

I tried to put absolute paths in java.project.sourcePaths but without effect.

I also tried to say that jar in sources are equals to path/to/sources/directory but it is not accepted.

Do you have any hints? Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple root workspaces.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Also use the following to add jar packages.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder*